# Login and authentication with Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like help from someone who has more experience with the Django REST framework, to tell me if the login and authentication system I created follows the right framework standards

I'm in doubt whether or not Django's login() function should be used in some part of my code, in the client views I want to avoid any direct access to the server, so I do all the logic involving the database in the microservice views, in my "UserLoginAPI" microservice view, should I use the login(request, user) function to log in the user? I saw in some discussions that I should replace login() with update_last_login(None, user) and that's what I did but I'm not sure if it's right

I would also like to know if my authentication middleware is correct, both to ignore public views and to check the token and update the user in the session

I don't have a lot of experience and I would appreciate it if you could tell me if my code is following the right standards or if there is something I can improve, a certain problem that I can avoid.

My login flow is:

1. The HTML form, through a POST request, sends the data "username" and "password" to the "login" client view
2. The "Login" client view receives this data and sends it to the "UserLoginAPI" microservice API
3. The "UserLoginAPI" microservice view receives this data and sends it to the "UserLoginSerializer" serializer for validation
4. The "UserLoginSerializer" serializer performs the necessary validations such as: Checks if the user is blocked, authenticates with Django's authenticate() function, checks if the user is not "None" and if the user is active, creates a token with oauth2.0 for this user and returns the authenticated user and the token to the "UserLoginAPI" view
5. The "UserLoginAPI" view receives the user and the token, updates the user's last login and sends the token to the "Login" client view
6. The "Login" client view receives the token and saves the token in the session and redirects the user to home page

My logout flow is:

1. The HTML form, through a POST request, sends the data "username" to the "logout" client view
2. The "Logout" client view receives this data and sends it to the "UserLogoutAPI" microservice API
3. The "UserLogoutAPI" microservice view receives this data and sends it to the "UserLogoutSerializer" serializer for validation
4. The "UserLogoutSerializer" validates the user, takes the active token and expires this token and returns the user to the "UserLogoutAPI" view
5. The "UserLogoutAPI" view receives the user and log out with django's logout() function and send a signal to django axes so it knows that the user has been logged out
6. The "Logout" client view redirects the user to login page

And in my middleware I check whether the view is public or not, if it is public the middleware is not executed because they are views that the user does not need to be logged in to access and if it is a view that is not public the middleware is executed and checks if there is a token in the session, it takes the token from the database that corresponds to the session token and if one does not exist, it returns an error. If a token exists, it checks whether it is already expiring and if it has, it returns an error and if it does not, it updates the user of the request for the user associated with the token.

"Login" and "Logout" are my client-side views, they receive a POST request from the HTML form and send this data to the microservices APIs

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        api_url = f'{BASE_URL}/UserLoginAPI/'  
        data = {
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
        }

        try:

            response = api_request.make_post_request(api_url, data=data)

            if response['status'] == status.HTTP_200_OK:
                access_token = response.get('access_token')
                request.session['access_token'] = access_token
                return redirect('home')
            elif response['status'] in [status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]:
                messages.error(request, response['message'], extra_tags='error')   

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            messages.error(request, 'Erro ao fazer login', extra_tags='error')

    return render(request, r'login\login.html')

def logout(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.user

        api_url = f'{BASE_URL}/UserLogoutAPI/'  
        data = {
            'username': username,
        }

        try:

            response = api_request.make_post_request(api_url, data=data)

            if response['status'] == status.HTTP_200_OK:
                return redirect('login')
            elif response['status'] in [status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]:
                messages.error(request, response['message'], extra_tags='error')

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            messages.error(request, 'Erro ao deslogar', extra_tags='error')
```

"UserLoginAPI" and "UserLogoutAPI" are my views in my authentication microservice

```
@authentication_classes([OAuth2Authentication])
@permission_classes([TokenHasReadWriteScope])
class UserLoginAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

        try:

            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            access_token = serializer.validated_data['access_token']

            update_last_login(None, user)
            return Response({'success': 'Login bem sucedido', 'access_token': access_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except ValidationError as e:
            error_message = str(e.detail['non_field_errors'][0])
            log_error(request.path, error_message, None)
            return Response({'error': error_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            log_error(request.path, str(e), None)
            return Response({'error': 'Erro ao fazer login'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        
@authentication_classes([OAuth2Authentication])
@permission_classes([TokenHasReadWriteScope])     
class UserLogoutAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        serializer = UserLogoutSerializer(data=request.data)

        try:

            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']

            logout(request)
            signals.user_logged_out.send(sender=User, request=request, user=user)
            return Response({'success': 'Usuário deslogado com sucesso'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        except ValidationError as e:
            error_message = str(e.detail['non_field_errors'][0])
            log_error(request.path, error_message, user)
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            log_error(request.path, str(e), user)
            return Response({'error': 'Erro ao deslogar'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

"UserLoginSerializer" e "UserLogoutSerializer" são os meus serializers

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')
        request = self.context.get('request')
      
        if AxesProxyHandler().is_locked(request):
            raise ValidationError('O usuário está bloqueado por múltiplas tentativas falhas de login, aguarde 30 minutos antes de tentar entrar novamente')

        user = authenticate(request=request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is None or not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError('Usuário ou senha inválidos')

        existing_token = AccessToken.objects.filter(
                user=user,
                expires__gt=timezone.now()
        ).first()

        if existing_token:
            access_token = existing_token
        else:
            access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(
                user=user,
                token=generate_token(),
                application=Application.objects.get(name='application_login'),
                expires=timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=60),
            )
        
        return {'user': user, 'access_token': access_token.token}  

class UserLogoutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username')

        user = User.objects.get(username=username)

        if not user or not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError('Usuário inválido')
        
        existing_token = AccessToken.objects.filter(
                user = user,
                expires__gt = timezone.now()
            ).first()

        existing_token.expires = timezone.now()  
        existing_token.save()
        
        return {'user': user}
```

"TokenAuthenticationMiddleware" is my authentication middleware

```
class TokenAuthenticationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.public_views_paths = set(settings.PUBLIC_VIEWS)

    def __call__(self, request):
        request_path = request.path

        if request_path not in self.public_views_paths:
            session_token = request.session.get('access_token')

            if session_token:
                try:
                    access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=session_token)
        
                    if access_token.expires < timezone.now():
                        request.user = AnonymousUser()
                        messages.error(request, "Sua sessão expirou, faça o login novamente")
                        return redirect('login')
                    else:
                        request.user = access_token.user
                        log_path(request_path, request.user)
                except AccessToken.DoesNotExist:
                    request.user = AnonymousUser()
                    messages.error(request, "Acesso negado, faça login para continuar")
                    return redirect('login')
  
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

My settings.py with public urls

```
PUBLIC_VIEWS = ['/', '/esqueci-a-senha/', '/redefinir-senha/']
```

Help to review my code and assess whether it meets the right development standards

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This,

Try `view.py`

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

    class LoginAPIView(APIView):
        serializer_class = LoginSerializer
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    
        def post(self, request):
            serializer = LoginSerializer(data = request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                user = authenticate(username=serializer.data['username'], password=serializer.data['password'])
                if user:
                    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                    return Response({'token': [token.key], "Sucsses":"Login SucssesFully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED )
                return Response({'Massage': 'Invalid Username and Password'}, status=401)
```

Try `serializers.py`

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "password")
```

Try `urls.py`

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='auth'),
]
```

Try `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

**Use This Method Your Work Become Easy**